# Google Drive 403 error, when downloading file

Tags: php, google-drive-api

i have problem with google drive

first of all I created an account on admin.google.com

there I got the credentials for **service account** and implemented them in my php application,

is enabled **Drive API** and **Drive SDK**
it works fine with upload and getting the files from drive.

but when i wont to download it writes 403

> 403. That’s an error.
>
> We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know.

I tried to download int 2 methods:

1. `$downloadUrl = $file->getWebContentLink();` **- error 403**

### Second:

```
  if ($downloadUrl) {
            $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
            $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
            //return Redirect::to( $downloadUrl);
            if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
                return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
            } else {
                // An error occurred.
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
            return null;
        }
```

- returns **content of the file** but wont download

if i access **direct download link** - its blank page

then i red in the internet that i need to delegate rights for my client id and i did it
[manage api clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6oQ8.png)

but the problem didn't disappear.

Comment: Check what scopes are you adding. Downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access. Additionally, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content. For example, an app using the drive.readonly.metadata scope would not be authorized to download the file contents. Users with edit permission may restrict downloading by read-only users by setting the restricted label to true. Try making the get request in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and see if you are able to get the file.